# Iteratively generating subplots in matplotlib by row and column - only final axes plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am writing code to plot cross correlations of every time-series in my data against all others, with two for-loops to index the row and column position respectively (column loop nested within the row loop).

Currently only the final axes (i.e. bottom right corner) of the figure is displaying any data, and each iteration of the loop appears to be plotting on this axes. I am wondering if I have made any obvious mistakes with the order of commands in the nested for loops, or if I am misinterpreting the input arguments to matplotlib functions like subplots....

The code is as below:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=data_num, ncols=data_num, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for n in range(data_num):  #row index
    for p in range(data_num):  # column index
        x = data_df.iloc[:,n]  #get data for ROI according to row index
        print(x.head())
        x = x.values
        y = data_df.iloc[:,p]  #get data for ROI according to column index
        print(y.head())
        y = y.values
        axes[n,p] = plt.xcorr(x,y,normed=True)     #axes [row,column] = cross correlation plot of above data
        print(f'plotting at index [ {n} , {p}]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a, perhaps unfortunate, way that pyplot and matplotlib works: you have to create the plots *on the respective axes*, not assign the result from a `pyplot.xcorr` call to an axes. Thus: `axis[n,p].xcorr(...)`. So the interface is suddenly somewhat more object-oriented than the usual direct `pyplot` calls.

All the plots ends up in just the last figure, because you are calling

```
plt.xcorr(x,y,normed=True)
```

It doesn't matter if you then assign the return value to the axes array elements, which you shouldn't, as that destroys the original axes array.
`plt.xcorr` will then plot all the data in the same plot on top of each other, because pyplot generally acts on the currently active axes, which is the last one created via `plt.subplots()`.

---

That's for an explanation. Here's an example solution (with random data and a simple scatter plot):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_num = 3

x = np.random.uniform(1, 10, size=(data_num, data_num, 20))
y = np.random.uniform(5, 20, size=(data_num, data_num, 20))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=data_num, ncols=data_num, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for n in range(data_num):  #row index
    for p in range(data_num):  # column index
        # Call `scatter` or any plot function on the 
        # respective `axes` object itself
        axes[n,p].scatter(x[n,p], y[n,p])
        print(f'plotting at index [ {n} , {p}]')
plt.savefig('figure.png')
```

and figure.png looks like (sorry, no colour or symbol variation, just bare bones scatter plots):

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, it was literally a case of changing that one line from 'axes[n,p] = plt.xcorr .......'   to 'axes[n,p].xcorr(....'

Really helpful, thank you!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the example. You would know how it could work if nrows or ncols was equal to 1 since it gives error in that case (IndexError: too many indices for array). Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @user140259 Use `plt.subplots(..., squeeze=False)` to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the flatten() command, e.g,:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 4, figsize = (15, 20))

for m in np.arange(0, 12):
    ax.flatten()[m].plot(stuff)
```